# Localhost vs Azure difference for MaxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: .net, azure, wcf, maxreceivedmessagesize

I have a WCF service that I expose on my localhost for development and on Azure for the production.
With the same config in app.config, it works on localhost and not on Azure.

Here is the WCF config :

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICentralSales" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" sendTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="20000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="21504000" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
```

In my WPF client, I have this config :

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICentralSales" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
        openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:55:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" />
```

Does anyone already faced this issue ?

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: Firstly, Azure offers several ways to host web sites: Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, Service Fabric, and Cloud Services. It is not clear if you have hosted the service on an Azure VM or Azure WebApps do provide details on your platform and if there is any specific error that you receive.

Comment: Hi Ajay, I use a Cloud service (classic) on Azure to host my WCF component. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After using a second Azure service it works fine ...
No great answer but it works for me